# satisfying the LTL formula in model

Tags: model-checking, nusmv

Is `AG(~q ∨ Fp)` LTL formula satisfy in model below? why or why not?

[image] model?

Comment: Don't rely on attaching a link. This question will go bad when link gets broken. Write the gist in the question. Or if that's an image, attach it right. That's not how to do it

Comment: @Aminah Nuraini thanks, I changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `AG(~q ∨ Fp)` is **not** an **LTL** formula, because the operator `AG` does not belong to *LTL*. I assume you meant `G(~q v Fp)`.

---

**Modeling**: let's encode the system in **NuSMV**:

```
MODULE main ()
VAR
  state : { S0, S1, S2, S3 };
  p : boolean;
  q : boolean;

ASSIGN
  init(state) := S0;
  next(state) := case
    state = S0 : {S1, S2};
    state = S1 : {S0, S3};
    state = S2 : {S0};
    state = S3 : {S3};
  esac;

INVAR state = S0 <-> (!p & !q);
INVAR state = S1 <-> ( p &  q);
INVAR state = S2 <-> (!p &  q);
INVAR state = S3 <-> ( p & !q);


LTLSPEC G(!q | F p)
```

And **verify** it:

```
~$ NuSMV -int
NuSMV > reset; read_model -i f.smv; go; check_property
-- specification  G (!q |  F p)  is false
-- as demonstrated by the following execution sequence
Trace Description: LTL Counterexample 
Trace Type: Counterexample 
-- Loop starts here
-> State: 2.1 <-
  state = S0
  p = FALSE
  q = FALSE
-> State: 2.2 <-
  state = S2
  q = TRUE
-> State: 2.3 <-
  state = S0
  q = FALSE
```

---

**Explanation**: So the LTL formula is **not satisfied by** the model. Why?

- `G` means that the formula is satisfied only if `~q v F p` is verified by *every* reachable state.
- State `S2` is s.t. `~q` is FALSE, so in order to satisfy `~q v F p` it must necessarily hold that `F p` is TRUE, that is *it is necessarily the case that sooner or later `p` becomes TRUE*.
- There exists an infinite path starting from `S2` s.t. `p` is always FALSE: the path that *jumps from `S2` to `S0` and back and never touches either `S1` or `S3`*.
- Contradiction: the *LTL* formula is not satisfied.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed.